# Modeling maps using trip data

Tags: model-selection

I am working on a problem where I need to identify the most likely used routes for a number of trips. The trips have their own starting and ending locations, along with distances covered and durations of these trips. I am not sure how to use the underlying road maps. Is indirectly modeling the route segments from these attributes a good idea? Any suggestion on how could I implement and test it? Some alternatives?

Comment: Kindly elaborate more on the objective of this exercise - "to identify most likely used routes for a number of trips". Do you consider a unique trip to be exact start point such as factory#1 to warehouse#2, or generic area on the map such as trip from east side of city to north side of city (which may include hundreds of geospatial coordinates in east side as starting points, and similarly hundreds of end points, but all clubbed together in 1 trip) ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application and the Data.Could you provide more details about the data of the trips? Do you have GPS-positions for the trips?

There are Libraries such as [Barefoot](https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot) which support you in map-matching, meaning that it maps your positions to the underlying map, in most cases OpenStreetMap. This library uses Hidden Markov Models for online and offline Map Matching. Maybe this could help you as well, when implementing your own model.